# PyQt5. Диалоговое окно

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()
        self.b = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Discard | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Yes)
        self.b.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Что нужно добавить/изменить в этом коде, чтобы диалоговое окно правильно отображалось(нельзя было изменить его размер и т. п.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить эти строки в `__init__`:

```
size = self.b.size()
self.b.setMinimumSize(size)
self.b.setMaximumSize(size)
```

Должно получиться так:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.show()
    self.b = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Discard | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Yes)
    self.b.show()

    size = self.b.size()
    self.b.setMinimumSize(size)
    self.b.setMaximumSize(size)
```

UPD1:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.show()
    self.b = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Discard | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Yes)
    self.b.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint| Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
    self.b.show()

    size = self.b.size()
    self.b.setMinimumSize(size)
    self.b.setMaximumSize(size)
```

Comment: а как сделать чтобы не было кнопок свернуть и восстановить?

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков дополнил ответ. Если нужно убрать также и крестик, то уберите параметр `Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint` из `self.b.setWindowFlags`, чтобы было так: `self.b.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)`